# Pandas Excel Merged Cell Parsing renaming Unnamed Column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to pandas. I'm trying to read an excel file as shown below using pandas (ExcelFile/read_csv):

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pF40.png)

When I do the following operations:

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile("fruit.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1', keep_default_na=False)
print df
```

I get the output:

```
   Sno  Apple  Unnamed: 2  Mango  Unnamed: 4
0    1   True          13  False           6
1    2  False           4   True           8
```

However, I want to get the output:

```
   Sno  Apple  AppleCount  Mango  MangoCount
0    1   True          13  False           6
1    2  False           4   True           8
```

I want rename the Unnamed Columns with the prefix as the Previous column's name then append 'Count' to that name. Is there a way to do that? Can this be done when reading the excel file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension you could do it with:

```
new_columns = [df.columns[i-1] + "Count" if df.columns[i].find("Unnamed") >= 0 else df.columns[i] for i in range(len(df.columns))]

In [20]: new_columns 
Out[20]: ['Sno', 'Apple', 'AppleCount', 'Mango', 'MangoCount']

df.columns = new_columns

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   Sno  Apple  AppleCount  Mango  MangoCount
0    1   True          13  False           6
1    2  False           4   True           8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this
to get the column values `headers = df.dtypes.index`

```
    new_column_name = headers[1] + "Count"
    df.rename(columns = {headers[2] : new_column_name} , inplace = True)
```

Accordingly you can write the logic